# Add timer to idle game

Tags: c#, timer

Ok, so as I go through learning C# I have run into an issue that I can't quite wrap my mind around.

I am building an idle game to learn more than books have taught me. Anyways, I am adding an "Auto-clicker" function. I thought that I should add a timer that would count to 1 second and add gold to the player's score. Maybe this is not the best way to approach this, but here is what I have so far:

Updated Code as per requested with Errors trying to load System.Timers.Timer;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;

namespace IdleClicker1
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public double gold = 0;
    public double goldPerClick = 1;
    public double upgradeCost = 20;
    public double autoMinerLevel = 0;
    public double autoMinerCost = 10;
    public System.Timers.Timer autoMineTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnGetGold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gold += goldPerClick;
        updateGoldShown();
    }

    public void updateGoldShown()
    {
        lblGold.Text = "Gold: " + gold.ToString();
        lblGoldPerClick.Text = "Gold per click: " + goldPerClick.ToString();
        lblAutoMiner.Text = "Auto-Miner Level: " + autoMinerLevel.ToString();
    }

    private void btnUpgradeClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gold >= upgradeCost)
        {
            gold = gold - upgradeCost;
            goldPerClick = goldPerClick + 1;
            upgradeCost = upgradeCost + 10;
            lblUpgradeCost.Text = "Cost to upgrade: " + upgradeCost.ToString();
            updateGoldShown();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry bub... not enough gold yet!", "Error buddy!");
        }
    }

    public void btnAutoMiner_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gold >= autoMinerCost)
        {
            autoMinerLevel++;
            gold = gold - autoMinerCost;
            autoMinerCost = autoMinerCost + 10;
            btnAutoMiner.Text = "Buy Auto-Miner for: " + autoMinerCost.ToString();
            updateGoldShown();

            //Adding a new timer
            System.Timers.Timer autoMineTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            autoMineTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            autoMineTimer.Interval = 1000;
            autoMineTimer.Enabled = true;
            autoMineTimer.Start();

        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry... not enough gold!", "Error again... yo!");
        }
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateGoldShown();
        btnGetGold.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

}

Basically, this is a very simple setup. I am just trying to learn by practice and applying myself. So when the user clicks on btnAutoMiner, it should start a timer that would add whatever the goldPerClick to the player's gold. I don't want an exact answer (otherwise I will never learn), but can someone abstractly help me out?

Comment: Well, you should at least first add the Timer and read its documentation and see how it works. Then if you can't get it to work you can ask about it. It is a very simple class to use.

Comment: I have added it before and couldn't get the gold to update... that is why I am trying to get an abstract view on how to update this.

Comment: Please add the code you tried, it's easier to help explain why it doesn't work

Comment: I have added the timer code. I pulled this from the MSDN, but now I get an error on build stating: Error 1 A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Timers.Timer' is a type not a namespace.

This is after I added `using System.Timers.Timer;` at the top of the code.

Comment: On a side note. You don't need all your `ToString`'s, because C# does that implicit if the left hand argument is a string.

Comment: Awesome @Bauss! I will remove them. I did think that I had to convert them. In the book I read, it discussed how to update text with number variables and taught me how to use `.ToString();`

Comment: You could also look into `string.Format`

Comment: What is this `desire2learn` tag?

Comment: I am not sure. It suggested it and I went with that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean this with the deepest respect but have you tried using the debugger and breakpoints to check if everything unfolds as expected.

I took the liberty to recreate your program, making a form that fits your code and what I got was a functional program that behaved as you described, when I click `GetGold` my gold increases by the `goldPerClick` value as expected, same with the `UpgradeClick`.

As I clicked `Buy Auto-Miner` I had a breakpoint at the buttons event method, the level went up by 1 as expected and the timer started just fine, again with a breakpoint I was monitoring the timers event method, which was called once per second as expected, so conclusion is that your program behaves just as its expected to logically.

However for the GUI there is a bit of a problem, the values is not being updated as the timer ticks so I would suggest looking there first, also some labels/buttons texts is only updated when certain buttons are clicked so again I would suggest putting all those in the same place and just call that method when needed.

Just some friendly design advice as well (without being too specific):
Consistency is important for good design, this means either use `value1 += value2` or  `value1 = value1 + value2` both is equally as right but mostly for consistency.
Using the right value types, using int values for simple numbers like 10 (sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, or char) and use floating point values for values like 1.5 (Double, Float)

I really hopes these tips helps you along your way and good luck with the project.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this as soon as I can. I am still really new to this and did not think about the debugging tools. I will try to be more consistent. The only other question is that I am trying to wrap my head around a function that would automatically update the screen (labels and button texts). I know that right now, it is simply only updating when a button is pressed. I will keep looking. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: for automaticly updating the screen just add the update method "updateGoldShown()" to your timer, normally for automatic update you want to have a reoccurring event like a timer tick or an async loop, but I'm personally just using the timer tick

Comment: So now I get this error with the `.Tick`! Error 1 'System.Timers.Timer' does not contain a definition for 'Tick' and no extension method 'Tick' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Timers.Timer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is after I added `using System.Timers.Timer;` at the top...

Comment: Can you update your code example to include these changes and I will have a look

Comment: I'm sorry for the delayed response, I suppose you mannaged to fix it yourself since you marked this as the answer, if this is the case I'm glad i could help, otherwise if you still have this issue I would gladly try to help you with this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the point of the timer is. Do you want to run btnAutoMiner_Click each second or on each click? If you add on each click, what is the point of the timer? Sorry, it's just a bit hard to understand your goals.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the timer documentation in case you needed it.

Edit: to perform a click from the timer, you can you use .PerformClick to simulate a click.

Comment: Essentially, I want it to automatically act as though I clicked the 'Get gold' button. This should allow the player to sit back and not have to click a button and watch their gold increase.

Comment: If you want the timer to act exactly like clicking the button, then just make the timer call the button's click event directly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `GetGold` button is working as you expect it to, you can programatically trigger it's click handler:

```
btnGetGold.PerformClick();
```

You would put this code inside the tick event handler for your Timer.